# How to get rid of CmisConstraintException on calling cancelCheckOut() on a document via CMIS API

Tags: exception, sharepoint, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I have a checked out document in `SharePoint 2013` with `version : 11274-2048`. Every time I call `doc.cancelCheckOut()` using the CMIS API, I am getting below exception :

```
com.datacert.core.common.exception.BaseApplicationException:
com.datacert.core.common.exception.BaseApplicationException:
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConstraintException:
The operation is attempting to perform an action on a non-current version of a Document that cannot be performed on a non-current version.
```

I have also tried fetching a fresh object from repository or refreshing the object using `doc.refresh()`.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using? Hard to tell what you're doing wrong without it

Comment: Are you calling cancelCheckOut() on the document or the PWC?

Comment: Yes.. I am calling cancelCheckout() to discard the checkout on PWC.